# Using boost::interprocess::named_mutex correctly

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having problems using named_mutex, which I am trying to use to determine if another instance of my application is running.

I defined a global variable:

```
named_mutex dssMutex{ open_or_create, "DeepSkyStacker.Mutex.UniqueID.12354687" };
```

In main() I then wrote:

```
    if (!dssMutex.try_lock()) firstInstance = false;
```

and at the end of main() after all the catch stuff I did:

```
dssMutex.unlock();
```

The problem I have encountered is that try_lock() is returning false when this is the only instance of my program in the system (just after a reboot).  I also see this in the debug log (which may just be an artefact of try_lock()):

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB838C4FD9 in DeepSkyStacker.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception at memory location 0x00007FF5FFF7EF00.
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- you should not `unlock` if `try_lock` returned false;
- you should be exception safe, which is easier with the `scoped_lock` helper
- Boost's interprocess locking primitives are not robust mutexes. This means that if your process gets hard-terminated without unlocking, the lock will be stuck. To the best of my knowledge the implementation(s) on Windows contain a "boot time" field which serves to recover the lock after a reboot, though, so your described scenario should really not be a problem.

#### *The Exception*

The exception shown should not be a problem unless it goes unhandled. If you're using Visual Studio you can configure the debugger to break on exceptions thrown or unhandled. The best explanation for the message is that it is handled internally. The worst explanation is that you're not handling it. In that case it will explain that the lock is not released.

Note that the exception might be cause by trying to `unlock` after failing to `try_lock`?

#### Code Sample

Here's how I'd use a deffered scope-lock to achieve exception safety:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int, char** argv) {
    bip::named_mutex dssMutex{bip::open_or_create, "UniqueID.12354687"};

    bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lk(dssMutex, bip::defer_lock);
    bool const firstInstance = lk.try_lock();

    std::cout << argv[0] << (firstInstance?" FRIST!":" SECOND") << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    std::cout << " Bye\n" << std::flush;
}
```

Coliru [cannot handle it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba43b07bee73fabd) but here's what that does locally:

[image]

### Signal Handling

Now, as mentioned, this is still not robust, but you can make it less bad by at least handling e.g. SIGINT (what happens on POSIX when you Ctrl-C in the terminal):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int, char** argv) {
    boost::asio::thread_pool ioc(1);
    boost::asio::signal_set ss(ioc, SIGINT, SIGTERM);
    ss.async_wait([](auto ec, int s) {
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            return;
        std::cerr << "signal " << s << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    });

    bip::named_mutex dssMutex{bip::open_or_create, "UniqueID.12354687"};

    bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lk(dssMutex, bip::defer_lock);
    bool const firstInstance = lk.try_lock();

    std::cout << argv[0] << (firstInstance?" FRIST!":" SECOND") << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::cout << " Bye\n" << std::flush;

    ss.cancel();
    ioc.join();
}
```

Now it's okay to interrupt the processes:

```
for a in {1..10}; do sleep "0.$RANDOM"; ./one; done& 
for a in {1..10}; do sleep "0.$RANDOM"; ./two; done&
sleep 3; pkill -INT -f ./one;
sleep 5; pkill -INT -f ./two
```

[image]

If you look closely, the handler doesn't actually do anything now. So likely you want to make sure it cleanly shuts down `main`.

Comment: That's enormously helpful thank you!

How might I expand that signal handler to make it shut the application cleanly?

Can I leave that code there on a Windows Build?

What purpose does the thread_pool object serve?

Comment: The exception is thrown when the mutex is constructed AFAICT.

Comment: Let me defer to docs for most of the questions: [signal_set](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/signal_set.html) and [thread_pool](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool.html). Let me [stress again](This means that if your process gets hard-terminated without unlocking, the lock will be stuck) that handling signals will *not* make interprocess mutex robust. See also [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=boost%20interprocess%20robust).

Comment: If construction raises the exception, then none of this is the issue. Instead, check your environment (e.g. permissions) and arguments (name restrictions?). Also, consider catching the exception to learn more about the cause?

Comment: The exception never escapes from the ctor ... So it must be being caught internally

Comment: In that case it's probably "none of our business" :) Implementation details are implementation details.